# How not to validate selected fields in serializer

Tags: python, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer to receive setting changes, and I want to check if at least one of not required settings is present in request. The validate function I have now will check `dot_id` and `user_id` like any other field, but how can I exclude this two fields from validation?

```
class FrameImageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    dot_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    is_active = serializers.BoolField(required=False)
    is_fullscreen = serializers.BoolField(required=False)
    resolution = serializers.ListField(
        required=False,
        min_length=4,
        max_length=4
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, data):
        if not data:  # except for dot_id and user_id...
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "At least one setting change needs to be present!"
            )
        return data
```

UPD:
For now I found solution like this:

```
clean_data = data[2:]  # since these two fields are always first
if not clean_data:
    ...
```

Isn't there a smarter way to do what I want?

UPD2:
Solution above leads to `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`
So for now the answer is:

```
    def validate(self, data):
        if len(data) == 2:
            ...
```

Comment: So what should happen if you pass a non-integer to `dot_id`?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem this will be reviewed in another validator and on the data sender side.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you want to exclude dot_id and user_id from validation, wich means that they will allways be considered as valid, whatever is the value given for this 2 fields (you probably check them somewhere else, I guess).

You are using object-level validation with 'validate', I think you could add field-level validation with ['validate_fieldname'](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) to set them always valid:

```py
# ...
    def validate_dot_id(self, value):
        """No check at all, just pass the value whatever it is"""
        return value
```

And same with user_id.

In my opinion, it could be better to use this field-level validations to actually check the validity of the given ids (but I don't know your project, you only can know).